# Missing secret token, secret key base when running my application in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key, token, production

I work with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1 and sorry but I am working on Windows

I have read a lot about this topic "Missing secret token, secret key base" but actually I do not understang anything.

I do not use Heroku, Git, Puma, Passenger or everything else I've read. I just thought I could instead of running `rails s` as usual run `rails s -e production` and see what is the version of my web application in production.

But I have the error "Missing secret_token and secret_key_base for production environment, set these values in config/secrets.yml"

I read about solutions using openSSL, `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<the long string>` but I do understand the solutions.

I thought it was a problem related to the system of connection by password I settled thanks to Rails tutorial of Micheal Hartl. So disabled SSL connection. But nothing change.

This is my `config/secrets.yml` :

```html
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

**Can someone explain how to concretely solve this issue ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GDMN I am sorry that everyone gave you such poor explanations and instructions. Ok onto it then, shall we......

First everyone is right you no longer need "secret_token", you do however need "secret_key_base". What this does is it secures your visitors connection and keeps your system and app more secure. That is a simple explanation but all you need to worry about at the beginners level.

Second the ENV stands for "Environment Variable" they are used in all operating systems and they refer to variables on the OS level that hold information that you do not want to be accessible t someone trying to gain access to your site. For instance in Ruby On Rails if you HARD CODE the secrety_token_base string/hash then I hacker can gain access by using your security_token against you. I have seen this happen and it is not pretty, if the individual is skilled enough then they can gain access to even your root/admin account.

Now on to setting it all up. I only know the linux way and I know you are looking for the windows method but this should at least give you an understanding to seek out the information relevant to your operating system.

First thing you would need to do is generate your secret_token_base by running

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

To my knowlege this is the way you do it in all Operating Systems. After you run the above command the console will return a string and you would need to copy it. Once copied you would run the following command:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=WhatYouJustCopied
```

Then we would check to make sure the Environment Variable SECRET_KEY_BASE is set by running:

```
env | grep -E "SECRET_TOKEN|SECRET_KEY_BASE"
```

If you do not have SECRET_TOKEN set you will only get the KEY_BASE.

If you want to learn more in depth information please visit this [link](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/) it may be a little dated but most of it is still relevant and conceptually it is the same.
I wish you luck on your new found ROR Adventure! It is fun once you get the hang of it!

Comment: Thanks so much. This explains a lot about `SECRET_KEY_BASE`

Answer (score 0):

From your command prompt, run:
    bundle exec rake secret

It will generate a long string of characters.  Copy this string and paste it into config/secrets.yml as follows:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <paste the string here>
```

Note: only do this if you are not using a public repository.  This key should not be accessible to anyone else.  An alternate, and more secure way of doing this is using an environment variable.  See this: http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/

Comment: I edited my post with what is currently in my `config/secrets.yml` file. In the url you sent me it is written that RAILS 4.1 has already integrated the right update to solve the problem of missing secret key base. So why am I having this problem?

Comment: In your edited post, you typed 'config/secrets/secrets.yml'.  Is it in the config directory or in a subdirectory called 'secrets'?  In the Rails console, type 'Rails.application.secrets'. Does it show the key?  If not, make sure your environment variable is set correctly in your production environment.

Comment: It was a mistake it is `config/secrets.yml` so my file `secrets.yml` is in my config directory. When I type `Rails.application.secrets`in the rails console it returns a hash with two params ; secret_key_base is a long string but `secret_token`is nil.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, secret_token is no longer used.  It is nil in my production environment as well.  Are you starting the console in the production environment (with -e production)?  Also, did you generate the key with 'rake secret'? The only other thing I can suggest you try is pasting the secret key directly into the secrets.yml file and see if you can get it to start.  It's not a best practice, but it's not a security risk as long as you don't put your code in a public directory.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you look inside the secrets.yml file, you will see where your secret_key_base is set for each of your environments. When you look at the production setting, it wants an env variable to initialize your secret_key_base. Normally, in production, you would want your app server to fetch the value from a general place in case you need to spin multiple servers up, you wouldn't have to hard-code your secret_key_base everywhere since that is not a secure way of setting that variable.

Basically, you will have to have that env variable set up on the machine that will run your rails app in production. There are so many different ways to set this.

What I have set up to initialize my ENV variables for production is have a separate yml file that is constructed like this

```
# config/env_provider.yml
production:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: "KEY GOES HERE"
  other_production_variables: #...etc
```

Then my separate servers will be told where to find this file before initializing the variables (This is not checked into version control). After the file is in place it will know to initialize the variables from the following code in environment.rb before your app initializes

```
#config/environment.rb
YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/env_provider.yml")[::Rails.env].each {|k,v| ENV[k] = v }
# This is before Rails.application.initialize!
```

The thing with this set up is to make sure that you do not have this file accessible to everyone to see, only allow your application servers to use it. Anyway, this is how I deal with ENV variables and deploy them to production. I hope this helps you.